# Is it possible to run an animation when the value of a TextBlock is changed?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, datatrigger

I am creating some `Animation`s to animate the change between values in a `Textblock`.
From what I've seen, I can use a `DataTrigger` to trigger then animation when the `Textblock`'s `value == something`, but is there a way to use the same mechanism to trigger when its changed? (That is, I don't care what the new value is just that its different)

I think this is supported in WPF using the `EventTrigger` with `TargetUpdated` but this doesn't seem to exist in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the [PropertyChangedTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj733159%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.